# Issue to install core3.1 VSBuildTools offline installer 2017 using workload

Tags: .net-core

When we trying to install the offline installer which is generated using below workload getting exited with errorlevel 1 . Any advise please?

.\vs_buildtools__140882496.1541481122.exe --layout . 
`--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools`
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools 
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools`
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools 
`Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack`
--lang en-US

**Error**

Something went wrong with the install.
If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist,version=4.7.3062.3' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=16389
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist,version=4.7.3062.3\dotNetFxLatest-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20200103140616_004_Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist.log"
        Return code: 16389
        Return code details: Unknown error (0x00004005)
    Log
        C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20200103140616_004_Microsoft.Net.4.7.2.FullRedist.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop build tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools,version=16.4.29511.114)
        MSBuild Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools,version=16.0.28516.191)
        Web development build tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools,version=16.4.29409.204)
    Impacted components
        .NET Framework 4.7.2 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=16.3.29207.166)
        .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack (Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack,version=16.0.28517.75)
        C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler,version=16.0.28714.129)
        MSBuild (Microsoft.Component.MSBuild,version=16.4.29429.68)

Comment: One more thing to be mentioned here. I have created a offline installer package with the same above mentioned workload definition around 10 months back. It used to work fine. Issue is being observed with the new installer package generated with same definition newly. Any advise please if i need to add any dependency and etc?

Comment: The same is happening for VSBuildTools 2019 offline installer even. Any advise please?